# Exit Stellar app on Ledger Nano S

Tags: ledger-nano

Once I enter the Stellar wallet on my Ledger Nano S, there is no option to "Quit App".  This option exists for the other wallets on my Ledger (Bitcoin, Ethereum, Litecoin).  The only way I have found to exit the Stellar wallet is to disconnect the USB cable.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to exit Stellar app on the Ledger. On the main view with the following text:

```
Use wallet to view accounts
```

Press right button 3 times, it should display `Quit app`. Now, press 2 buttons at the same time.